# Find a set of vector B

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, combinations

Find a set of vector B such that $$\operatorname{span}(B)=\{(x,y,z,w)^T\mid 2x+y+w=0, y+2z=0\}$$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

This is what I have so far I don't know if it is correct.

$$
  x\begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 \\
    b_1 \\
    c_1 \\
    d_1 
  \end{pmatrix}+ y\begin{pmatrix}
    a_2 \\
    b_2 \\
    c_2 \\
    d_2 
  \end{pmatrix}+ z\begin{pmatrix}
    a_3 \\
    b_3 \\
    c_3 \\
    d_3 
  \end{pmatrix}+w \begin{pmatrix}
    a_4 \\
    b_4 \\
    c_4 \\
    d_4 
  \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
where $2x+y+w=0$ and $y+2z=0$.
Then $w=-2x-y$, $y=2z$, $w=-2x+2z$.
Then 
$$ x\begin{pmatrix}
    b_1 \\
    b_2 \\
    b_3 \\
    b_4 
  \end{pmatrix}+ y\begin{pmatrix}
    α_1 \\
    α_2 \\
    α_3 \\
    α_4 
  \end{pmatrix}+ z\begin{pmatrix}
    -2c_1 \\
    -2c_2 \\
    -2c_3 \\
    -2c_4 
  \end{pmatrix} +w\begin{pmatrix}
    -2b-α_1 \\
    -2b-α_2 \\
    -2b-α_3 \\
    -2b-α_4 
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus $$2b+α_1+-2b_1-α_1=0$$ and $$α_1-2c=0$$ where $$c_1=1/2α_1$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you deduced $w=-2x-y$ and $y+2z=0$.

What you need to find is the solution set of
$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y+w=0 \\
y+2z=0
\end{cases}
$$
so $w=-2x-y$ and $y=-2z$; hence $w=-2x+2z$, so the vectors are of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ -2b \\ b \\ -2a-2b \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary. Since
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ -2b \\ b \\ -2a-2b \end{pmatrix}
=
a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
+
b\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
you are done.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following constrains imply that the Span (B) is a two dimentional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

$$ \begin{cases}
2x+y+w=0 \\
y+2z=0
\end{cases}$$

Thus it suffices to find two linearly independent vectors such as  $$b_1 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$ b_2= \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Which satisfy the constrains and let $$B= \text {{$b_1$, $b_2$}} $$